# using hashes to create a class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

when trying to create a class with a single argument, I am getting the following error:  NameError: undefined local variable or method `radius' for #<Circle:0x007fdcda2b75c8> from circle_constructor.rb:13:in`initialize'

```
class Circle
  def initialize(circle_constructor = {})
    circle_constructor =  {@radius => radius, @diameter => diameter}
      @radius = radius
      @diameter = diameter
  end
end
```

Comment: i don't really understand what you are trying to do...

Comment: trying to create a class with a  single argument that would allow the developer to specify whether the value supplied is the diameter or the radius of the circle.

Comment: Classes don't have arguments. Methods have arguments.  Perhaps you mean you want to define a class' initialize method that has one argument.

Answer (score 1):

if i understand you correctly you try to initialize `@radius` and `@diameter` with the hash you got as a parameter so try the following:

```
class Circle
  def initialize(circle_constructor = {})
      ## circle_constructor =  {@radius => radius, @diameter => diameter}
      ## you are inserting wrongly values to local variable inside constractor wothout doing nothing with it so remove it or do this:
      ## @circle_constructor =  { radius: radius, diameter: diameter }
      ## make sure you populate radius and diameter local variables before.
      @radius = circle_constructor[:radius]
      @diameter = circle_constructor[:diameter]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Ruby doesn't support this out of the box, but you can use [Hashie](https://github.com/intridea/hashie) library for this. It has several hash variants and dash would work well for this.

```
require 'hashie/dash'

class Circle < Hashie::Dash

  property :radius, required: true
  property :diameter, required: true

end

# USAGE
Circle.new(radius: 10, diameter: 5)
```

(On a side note, it's odd that your circle accepts both a radius and a diameter. Unless it's user input such as a quiz, you should be able to derive one from the other, so it would normally only have one constructor param and the other would be a method.)

Comment: Should property _:dimension_ be _:diameter_?